# J2Me installation via OTA

Tags: java-me, installation, midp, over-the-air

I'm trying to install my application midlet via OTA. I used apache tomcat 6 as the ota server, and create a small project in the webapps folder which contains application.jad, application.jar and welcome.html which has a link point to the .jad file. I tested the installation using sun emulator it installs just fine.

But when I tried to install on a mobile by typing the url: **serverurl**:8080/JMEAPP/welcome.html, it gives an error saying "Operation you request cannot be proceeded". Error number is 502.

Frustrating thing is installation works on one phone (SH06A). In all other phones I tested belongs to japan's third largest mobile network provider (I dunno whether it's ok to mention brand names here, so I didn't, I'm sorry). All of those phones gives above mentioned error (But none of them are NOKIA, we installed it on a nokia phone by bluetooth, it works.). But all of them didn't even seems to read the jad file.

Therefore, can you one tell me the issue here. Is it a security issue? or can network providers can block their phones so that we cannot install anything on their phones? Or is this a compatibility issue?

I couldn't find a reason for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The [502](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E502.html) is a clue.  This indicates that something is going wrong between your handset and your server, probably in the bit between the MNO network and your server.  If you just use a browser on your desktop computer to look at the welcome.html file does all seem ok?

It's not quite clear from your question - you say the SH06A worked - was that OTA?  But with a different MNO to all the ones that failed?

In the UK there is some, rather unpredictable, filtering in the proxy/caches that MNOs operate.  It might be that your problem MNO doesn't like sending traffic to the specific 8080 port.  You might try running on a different port (ideally 80) or create a virtual server so no port appears in the URL.

Your observation on JAD files sounds correct - the handsets are not loading the welcome.html, so they don't have the JAD URL to attempt to load.

Comment: Thank you for your answer martin, I'll really appreciate it. To explain more, we installed it on the SH06A using OTA. It worked. But that phone comes from a different network provider. All all other phones I checked, which belongs to the network provider that I mentioned in my question, it didn't work. 

As you said, it might be the port, because I used to port 8484. I'll try to set up a virtural server. But I have never set up a virtual server for tomcat before, is it possible?

Comment: @nuwan - Sorry, not that familiar with the intricacies, but here's a link that purports to explain how to set up virtual hosts with Tomcat: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/tomcat-vhost.html  HTH

Comment: I figured out a way to redirect port so that I can use port 80 in the url. So, now I can access the "welcome.html" file. But when I click in the file, to get the .jad file, it gives a new error saying,

The error occurred. The response is illegal. (WJ46297E)

エラーが発生しました。レスポンスが不正です。(WJ46297E)

Plz help........

Comment: @nuwan - great, sounds like you've made some progress. I don't recognise that error. It might be that your server is not using the correct MIME type for jad files. It should be "text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor". If that is not the issue suggest you post a new SO question for the error because not so many people will look at this question now. Also, if the input here has helped you could up vote and/or accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check what application mime type is being sent out when you download a jad and a jar. If it is not the following then you might have to edit the conf files appropriately to send the mime types

jad - text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor
jar - application/java-archive

You can sniff the network packets using some packet sniffing tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.com)